# Change CSS background gradient via Javascript on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, gradient, background-color, addeventlistener

I'm trying to change one of two background colours of a gradient via Javascript. The color is scroll dependent. Somehow a single color works but not a gradient.

```
const [red, green, blue] = [0, 200, 0];
const hasGradient = document.querySelector('.has-gradient');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let y = 1 + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / 150;
  y = y < 1 ? 1 : y
  const [r, g, b] = [red/y, green/y, blue/y].map(Math.round);
  hasGradient.style.background = `linear-gradient(rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}), rgb(255,0,0));`;
  console.log(`linear-gradient(rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}), rgb(255,0,0))`)
});
```

Thx for any input!

Answer (score 1):

You using a `;` in your string.

```
  hasGradient.style.background = `linear-gradient(rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}), rgb(255,0,0));`;
```

Should be:

```
  hasGradient.style.background = `linear-gradient(rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}), rgb(255,0,0))`;
```

> Note: It is not possible to set styles by assigning a string to the style property, e.g. element.style = "color: red;". To set the style of an element, append a "CSS" property to style and specify a value

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/faod18mL/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I don't need the ';'
I'll try it!

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Do you maybe have any tips on how I can adjust the code so that it shifts from one color to another instead of from one color to black? Maybe something like: `if(red/150 == 50) {//stop adding to red here} ?

Answer (score 1):

Y is often <0. You need to make it always positive with y = y < 0 ? -y : y.

```js
const [red, green, blue] = [0, 255, 0];
const hasGradient = document.querySelector('.has-gradient');
hasGradient.style.background = `rgb(${red},${green},${blue})`

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let y = 1 - (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / 150;
  y = y < 0 ? -y : y
  const [r, g, b] = [red/y, green/y, blue/y].map(Math.round);
  hasGradient.style.background = `linear-gradient(rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}), rgb(255,0,0))`;
  console.log(y)
  console.log(`linear-gradient(rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}), rgb(255,0,0))`)
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 7000px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="has-gradient">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips! Unfortunately it glitches

Comment: How it would go from blue to red? I tried to change the RGBs but don't work..

Comment: @FilipeOS i changed `const [red, green, blue] = [0, 200, 0];` to `const [red, green, blue] = [0, 0, 200];` and it works pretty well. Note that i edited my answer to fix glitchy effect right at the beggining of scrolling

Comment: I change the first to a custom blue and the next to a custom pink, it don't know. Pink stay pink and blue goes black. Should be entire blue and on scroll go blue to pink